# Image position resets to zero at runtime in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I have set up some image buttons on my preview, set their position in the xml file but when I run the program all the images move to (0,0).

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="126dp"
    android:layout_height="117dp"
    android:background="@null"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/sad"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="82dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="200dp" />
```

The IDE prompts me that:

The layout editor allows you to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and it records the current position with designtime attributes (such as layout_editor_absoluteX.) These attributes are not applied at runtime, so if you push your layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a different location than shown in the editor. To fix this, make sure a widget has both horizontal and vertical constraints by dragging from the edge connections.

How do I set the values for the images at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout and set left and top margins to place your view.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        android:background="@null"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sad"
        android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for